# Code Behind to manage AD users for a CRM system

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory

I have big class in ASP.NET WebForms (legacy). I use VS 2012.

I want to evaluate **Conditions** and execute **Actions - Commands** like:

> Create in AD
>
> Delete in AD
>
> Enable in CRM
>
> DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM)
>
> Delete Licenses CRM
>
> Send Email Warning 1
>
> Send Email Warning 2
>
> ShowNotification

***TODO code:*** (without error handling)

```
if (ActionTypePage == ActionType.Modification || ActionTypePage == ActionType.MyDataMod)


        if (user.Enabled && isEmployer)
        {
            // 1a) (Employer) NOT exists in AD ==> Error
            if (!existsinAD)
            {
                ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                return;
            }

            // 1b) If Employer exists in AD ==> Enable in CRM (If false, New Request to CRM)
            // Enable in CRM (If false, New Request CRM)
        }

        if (user.Enabled && !isEmployer)
        {
            // 2a) If NOTEmployer NOT exists in AD ==> Create user in AD y Enable in CRM (If false, New Request CRM)
            if (!existeinAD)
            {
                //  Create in AD

                // Enable in CRM (If false, New RequestCRM)
            }

            // 2b) If NOTEmployer exists in AD ==> Warning (Email) y Enable in CRM (If false, New RequestCRM)
            if (existeinAD)
            {
                // Send Email Warning
                // Enable in CRM (If false, New RequestCRM)
            }

        }


        // DES-Enable
        // 1a) If (Employer) NOT exists in AD ==> Error
        // 1b) If (Employer) exists in AD ==> DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM) - Delete Licenses CRM 
        if (!user.Enabled && isEmployer)
        {
            if (!existsinAD)
            {
               ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                return;
            }

            // DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM) 
            //  Delete Licenses CRM 

        }

        if (!user.Enabled && !isEmployer)
        {
            // 2a) If NOTEmployer NOT exists in AD ==> Warning (Email) y  DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM) - Delete Licenses CRM 
            //  Delete Licenses CRM 
            if (!existeinAD)
            {
                 // Send Email Warning
                // DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM) 
                //  Delete Licenses CRM 
            }

            // 2b) If NOTEmployer exists in AD ==> Eliminar de AD y DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM) - Delete Licenses CRM 
            if (!existeinAD)
            {
                // Delete in AD
               // DesEnable in CRM (Delete in CRM) 
              //  Delete Licenses CRM 

            }
        }
```

Full code:

```
  if (ActionTypePagina == ActionType.Modificacion || ActionTypePagina == ActionType.MisDataM)
            {

            var bAccionOk = false;
            var sPassword = DataPersonales.GenerarPassword();
            var dpDataPersonales = fillDataPersonales(sPassword);
            var userPortal = fillUserPortal();

            var isEmployer = userPortal.IsEmployerRolAorRolB();
            var existsEnAD = ADOperations.ExistsUserEnActiveDirectory(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

            //var userConsultado = setUserConsultado();
            if (userPortal.bIs_Enabled.Value && isEmployer)
            {
                // 1a) Si RolA, RolB (employer) NO exists en AD ==> Error
                // 1b) Si RolA, RolB (employer) exists en AD ==> Enable en CRM (si false, Request New CRM)
                if (!existsEnAD)
                {
                    var msg = String.Format("El employer {0:-10} no exists en ActiveDirectory", dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                    var log = String.Format("User: {0, -15} - Error: {1:-100}", dpDataPersonales.sUser, msg);
                    LoggerAD.Trace("[AdminDataUsers] - Modificación ERROR. ExistsUserEnActiveDirectory. " + log);

                    ((NsiMaster)Master.Master.Master).ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                    return;
                }

                // Enable en CRM (si false, Request New CRM)
                var okEnable = AdminManager.EnableUserEnCrm(dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                if (!okEnable)
                {
                    var msg = "No es posible habilitar al usuario en CRM. Realice una Request New CRM";
                    ((NsiMaster)Master.Master.Master).ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                    return;
                }

            }

            if (userPortal.bIs_Enabled.Value && !isEmployer)
            {
                // 2a) Si NO RolA, RolB (mediador) NO exists en AD ==> Alta en AD y Enable en CRM (si false, Request New CRM)
                if (!existsEnAD)
                {
                    var permisoOK_AltaAD = (UserLogado.EsMediadorMA() || UserLogado.IsEmployerRolAorRolB())
                        && !userPortal.IsEmployerRolAorRolB();

                    var okAD = false;
                    if (permisoOK_AltaAD)
                    {
                        var msgEstadoAD = "";
                        var NombreCompleto = dpDataPersonales.sNombre + " " + dpDataPersonales.sApellido1 + " " + dpDataPersonales.sApellido2;
                        okAD = ADOperations.AddUserEnActiveDirectory(dpDataPersonales.sUser, dpDataPersonales.sPassword,
                            dpDataPersonales.sNombre,
                            dpDataPersonales.sApellido1 + " " + dpDataPersonales.sApellido2
                            , NombreCompleto
                            , isEmployer, UserConsultado.sUser_Aire, UserConsultado.sCartera
                            , dpDataPersonales.sEmail, dpDataPersonales.sTelefonoFijo, dpDataPersonales.sTelefonoMovil
                            , out msgEstadoAD);

                        if (!okAD)
                        {
                            var log = String.Format("User: {0, -15} - Error: {1:-100}", dpDataPersonales.sUser, msgEstadoAD);
                            LoggerAD.Trace("[AdminDataUsers] - Modificación ERROR. AddUserEnActiveDirectory. " + log);
                        }

                        if (okAD)
                        {
                            var log = String.Format("User: {0, -15} - Password: {1:-10}", dpDataPersonales.sUser, PassManager.ShowPassword(dpDataPersonales.sPassword));
                            LoggerAD.Trace("[AdminDataUsers] -  Modificación. AddUserEnActiveDirectory. " + log);
                        }
                    }

                    // Enable en CRM (si false, Request New CRM)
                    var okEnable = AdminManager.EnableUserEnCrm(dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                    if (!okEnable)
                    {
                        var msg = "No es posible habilitar al usuario en CRM. Realice una Request New CRM";
                        ((NsiMaster)Master.Master.Master).ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                        return;
                    }
                }

                // 2b) Si NO RolA, RolB (mediador) exists en AD ==> Warning (Email) y Enable en CRM (si false, Request New CRM)
                if (existsEnAD)
                {
                    //  Warning (Email)
                    AdminManager.EnviarEmailWarning(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

                    // Enable en CRM (si false, Request New CRM)
                    var okEnable = AdminManager.EnableUserEnCrm(dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                    if (!okEnable)
                    {
                        var msg = "No es posible habilitar al usuario en CRM. Realice una Request New CRM";
                        ((NsiMaster)Master.Master.Master).ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                        return;
                    }
                }

            }


            // DES-Enable
            // 1a) Si RolA, RolB (employer) NO exists en AD ==> Error
            // 1b) Si RolA, RolB (employer) exists en AD ==> DesEnable en CRM (Delete en CRM) - Delete de Licencias CRM 

            if (!userPortal.bIs_Enabled.Value && isEmployer)
            {
                if (!existsEnAD)
                {
                    var msg = String.Format("El employer {0:-10} no exists en ActiveDirectory", dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                    var log = String.Format("User: {0, -15} - Error: {1:-100}", dpDataPersonales.sUser, msg);
                    LoggerAD.Trace("[AdminDataUsers] - Modificación ERROR. ExistsUserEnActiveDirectory. " + log);

                    ((NsiMaster)Master.Master.Master).ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);
                    return;
                }

                // DesEnable en CRM (Delete en CRM)
                AdminManager.DeshabilitarUserEnCrm(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

                // Delete de Licencias CRM 
                AdminManager.DarDeDeleteComoUserCrmActivo(dpDataPersonales.sUser);
            }

            if (!userPortal.bIs_Enabled.Value && !isEmployer)
            {
                // 2a) Si NO RolA, RolB (mediador) NO exists en AD ==> Warning (Email) y DesEnable en CRM (Delete en CRM) - Delete de Licencias CRM 
                if (!existsEnAD)
                {
                    // Warning (Email)
                    AdminManager.EnviarEmailWarning(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

                    // DesEnable en CRM (Delete en CRM)
                    AdminManager.DeshabilitarUserEnCrm(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

                    // Delete de Licencias CRM 
                    AdminManager.DarDeDeleteComoUserCrmActivo(dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                }

                // 2b) Si NO RolA, RolB (mediador) exists en AD ==> Delete de AD y DesEnable en CRM (Delete en CRM) - Delete de Licencias CRM 
                if (!existsEnAD)
                {
                    // Delete de AD
                    var res = ADOperations.DeleteUserEnActiveDirectory(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

                    // DesEnable en CRM (Delete en CRM)
                    AdminManager.DeshabilitarUserEnCrm(dpDataPersonales.sUser);

                    // Delete de Licencias CRM 
                    AdminManager.DarDeDeleteComoUserCrmActivo(dpDataPersonales.sUser);
                }
            }
```

Any suggestions for refactoring, not code-smell, maybe with error handling too?

Comment: Please do not update your code after you've received answers. ["Do not change the code in the question after receiving an answer. Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site."](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: ***update code here: http://pastebin.com/eEbRKt4C***

Comment: Your last edit was rather borked; it introduced several thousand non-characters. I have decided to roll it back, lest some poor browser chokes on a 8000-character line for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

[Do NOT use Hungarian notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229045(v=vs.110).aspx): `bAccionOk`, `sPassword`,...

Do NOT use non-alphanumeric characters: `bIs_Enabled`, `permisoOK_AltaAD`,...

---

Concatenating strings quickly becomes unwieldy. This is already difficult, for instance: `var NombreCompleto = dpDataPersonales.sNombre + " " + dpDataPersonales.sApellido1 + " " + dpDataPersonales.sApellido2;`. Moreover, considering that this concatenates three properties of `dpDataPersonales`, why isn't `NombreCompleto` a property of `dpDataPersonales`?

(Also, `NombreCompleto` should be camelCase if it is a mere variable.)

---

`ADOperations.AddUserEnActiveDirectory(` seems to take a dozen(!) or so parameters. Instead, pass a single class where each of these is a property; that way it is easier to read and there's less chance of making an error. Also, considering that much of these parameters are part of `dpDataPersonales`, why not simply pass that class instead of copying over its values?

---

What is `LoggerAD`? To me this doesn't look like something that should be in your WebForms code behind, but you haven't provided us with enough information.

---

You code is partly in English, party in Spanish (I think). Same for your comments. This is confusing; ideally I'd advise you to stick to English.

---

Try to move your code from code-behind to specific classes. Specifically, split you UI from your business logic.

I get the impression much of the logic from your second code sample can and should be in a business logic class (or multiple), with communication between UI being limited to a parameter class being used to pass parameters from the UI to the back-end, while another class returns the results (success/error) and various messages.

Look at the variables you define on top: `bAccionOk` isn't used anywhere I think, and `sPassword`, `dpDataPersonales`, `userPortal` etc. are only used in code that looks to be back-end code. The only things that look to be relevant to the UI are calls like `((NsiMaster)Master.Master.Master).ShowNotification(msg, CommunicationType.Error, true);`, and its various parameters can all come from the "response class" I talked about earlier.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my code. It was in Spanish, now translate full to English. `LoggerAD` class for logging Ent.Library to file. Much of the logic should be in a business logic class (or multiple), maybe using any ***good pattern and practices***.

Answer (score 2):

> Any suggestions for refactoring, **not code-smell**...

If you want to refactor your code you should **start with code-smell**. Currently it looks like at least four or five developers each with different coding-conventions have written this:

```
bIs_Enabled // with an underscore
dpDataPersonales // hungarian-notation
isEmployer // wow, this one is correct ;-)
existsinAD // with 's'
existeinAD // without 's'    
existsEnAD // ...
```

No wonder you have difficulties to refactor it. It's nearly impossible to read it.

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my code. It was in Spanish, now translate full to English. Like says @BCdotWEb _Much of the logic should be in a business logic class (or multiple)_, maybe using any ***good pattern and practices***.

Comment: ***update code here: http://pastebin.com/eEbRKt4C***